# Java UI: set swing components behavior on resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-8

I am having a hard time to properly set the way my swing components behave on resize.

I have two problems with that interface:
[image: expected]

A: The toggle button at the beginning of each row is here to collapse/expand the text. All the elements are contained in a JLayeredPane. On the button click, I edit the pane's height to expand or collapse the content (either 31 or 310). `Expand` works fine an pushes the elements below. On the other hand, `collapse` does hide the text but leaves all the elements in position. Here is my code:

```
private void expandText(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) evt.getSource();
    Container parent = button.getParent();
    Dimension size = parent.getSize();
    String icon;

    if (button.isSelected()) {
        size.height = 310;
        icon = "/org/cytoscape/ocsana/resources/images/minus.png";
    } else {
        size.height = 31;
        icon = "/org/cytoscape/ocsana/resources/images/plus.png";
    }

    parent.setSize(size);
    try {
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(icon)).getScaledInstance(-1, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

    backgroundPane.revalidate();
    backgroundPane.repaint();
}
```

B: The screenshot above is the minimum size of the window. When I resize the window horizontally, the inner pane only resize to the value of `min + (frame.width - min) / 2` meaning my right scrollbar does not stick to the right side of the frame.

See below a demonstration of the both problems:
[image: result]

Comment: Regarding point B: Setting the size of my `backgroundPane` (contained by the `JScrollPane` whose size is now set too) and my frame solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [camickr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23250609/1504398) and comments, see how I solved it:

---

**Point A** is due to my free layout used in NetBeans. I did not succeed to fix my code so I changed the structure of my elements. It is probably not optimal and does not use all the swing concepts right, but it works the way I want.

I have a `JLayeredPane` in the background that uses a `GridBagLayout`. This background pane contains one column of `JPanel` of height 30 and 260, one for the **summary line**, the other one for the **details**.

[image]

The expand/collapse function controlled by the `JToggleButton` works by hiding the below panel `belowPanel.setVisibility(false)`. No need for repack or anything, just that. Here is how the code looks like without changing the button's icon:

```
private void inverseVisibility(JToggleButton expand, JPanel target) {
    if (expand.isSelected()) {
        target.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        target.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

As I only wanted the elements to resize horizontally, all my panels have `Horizontal` as `Fill` value and `Northwest` as `Anchor`. I've set the `weightX = 1; weightY = 0`. Finally I added a panel in the bottom with a `Southwest` anchor and fill `both` along with both weights to `1` (not sure it changes anything but this way I am certain that it will fill all the blank space at the bottom it the window is resized at a bigger size than its content).

---

**Point B** has been solved by taking my background panel, that fit in my `Frame`, and putting it into a `JScrollPane`. The error I had was due to the Netbeans editor that did not properly stick the scroll pane to the side of the frame, due to incoherences in the sizes defined in both the frame and the scroll pane. My advise to you if you are using this tool is to set the fewest values as possible as a lot of values are heavily interconnected by the gui designer.

[Get the full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwh-sPx-NX2oQUJfRFNTWFJjckk/edit) (95,864 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

How does your expand/collapse code work? Do you just make component visible/invisible, or do you add remove components from the panel?

> On the other hand, collapse does hide the text but leaves all the elements in position.

If you add/remove components then the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

> meaning my right scrollbar does not stick to the right side of the frame.

It depends on the layout manager you are using. I would guess the easiest would be to use a GrigBagLayout. It allows you to "fill" the space available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

> All the elements are contained in a JLayeredPane.

Not sure why you are using a layered pane. By default a layered pane doesn't use a layout manager.

Comment: Regarding point A: I have edited my post to include the code. I have added `int i = backgroundPane.getIndexOf(parent); backgroundPane.remove(i); backgroundPane.add(parent, i);` before the revalidate(). The parent is my JLayeredPane, I have 6 of them, one for each line. It does refresh the layout but the elements are moving oddly in a way that I can not see a pattern. For those interested here is the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwh-sPx-NX2oZEVZWms5b3VpdE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ` The parent is my JLayeredPane, I have 6 of them, one for each line.` - doesn't make sense to me. A layered pane is used to display components on top of one another (ie. the Z axis). You components are displayed vertically so you should be using a layout manager. `parent.setSize(size);` - whenever I see code like that it implies you are using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with a layout manager so the components will automatically resize/reposition as the frame size changes.

Comment: The ui has been build using NetBeans meaning there is `GroupLayout` everywhere. When I use `layeredpane.remove(scrollpane)` the elements successfully resize, same if I resize the window. When I add the element back, the `JLayeredPane` keeps its small size, hiding the `JScrollPane` it contains. I have updated my code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwh-sPx-NX2oZEVZWms5b3VpdE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't help since I never look at layout code generated by an IDE. I also, don't look at code unless it is presented in a proper `SSCCE` in this forum, not on an external website.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add a listener to the frame so have an action on event when the frame is being resized. And then pack() the frame.

```
public final class TestFrame extends JFrame {

(...)

    this.getRootPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

             this.pack();
             this.revalidate();

        }
    });

}
```

It you are using the paint graphic method, you should as well repaint() your frame.

In that method you can also manyally set the preferred size of the window by computing it based on e.getWidth()

Comment: Seems a bit extreme and inefficient as this method would be often called. I like camickr solution better with remove and add.